# I have an incorrect asset_host, but can't change it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the console, development mode:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host 

=> 192.168.2.55
```

which happens to be a previous DHCP address.

I checked:

RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/development.rb

RAILS_ROOT/config/environment.rb

... and there is nothing set here.  Even if I add

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://127.0.0.1"
```

to development.rb, I get the old DHCP address.  I've tried clearing browser caches, name server caches, but am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is RAILS_ROOT/config/facebooker.yml

```
callback_url: http://192.168.2.55
```